# NLFFI: wrong values are sent to C function arguments of type "short"

Tags: c, sml, ffi, smlnj

It seems like a bug in NLFFI SML/NJ implementation. C function is

```
void f0
    ( short a0
    , short a1
```

and so on

```
    , short a7
    ) {
    printf ("a0 == %hx\n", a0);
    printf ("a1 == %hx\n", a1);
```

and so on

```
    printf ("a7 == %hx\n", a7);
}
```

I compile it by

> gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -o libdelme.so _.c

and install. Invocation from C

```
f0 (0x7654, 0x3210, 0x9876, 0x5432, 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9012, 0x3456);
```

prints correct values, and invocation from ML

```
F_f0.f' (0x7654, 0x3210, 0x9876, 0x5432, 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9012, 0x3456);
```

prints this

```
a0 == 7654
a1 == 9876
a2 == 1234
a3 == 9012
a4 == 0
a5 == 1800
a6 == 3cf0
a7 == ee00
```

A similar effect is with `signed char`. It seems that my C library is expecting arguments aligned to 2^5-bit address and NLFFI does not align them.

I was encountered this error when creating a binding to [XCB](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/), so I can't change its header files, function prototypes and such. Everything is already prepared in my Linux distribution.

Maybe it is related that I cross-compile, i.e. compile to x86 code on AMD64.

SML/NJ version

```
$ pacman -Q smlnj
smlnj 110.77-1
```

Comment: Didn't knew it is possible to add after a variable argument list additional specific arguments. How does this work?

Comment: @Zaibis: “...” means “and so on”. Right, that is confusing. :)

Comment: ahhh right, now I get the sense of your question >.<

Answer (score 0):

The `h` specifier in the `printf` format string says to expect a `short int`; however, you are casting the `short ints` to `int`, which is redundant and unnecessary since C promotes `shorts` to `int` by default.

Remove the `h` specifier and the casts.

Comment: Default argument promotion in `printf` anyway converts `short` argument to `int`.

Comment: @ouah That occurred to me just minutes after I wrote my answer. You're absolutely right so I'm editing to fix. Thanks!

Comment: 0. According to Wikipedia, "h" expects `int` promoted from `short`. Without "h" it prints some numbers with 8 digits instead of 4. 1. Your suggestion does not fix the error.

Comment: Wikipedia is completely incorrect and Wikipedia is not where you should be going for programming information in the first place. Try an actual programming site such as cplusplus.com. I tested your code and reproduced the error. I then removed the casts and the `h` specifier and it worked.

Comment: @CareyGregory really not good to generalize like that, some programming concepts are explained quite well in wikipedia.

Comment: @CareyGregory, checked again, does not work. What SML/NJ version do you use?

Comment: @Claptrap Some wiki articles are fine, sure, but with technical info one small error can have major detrimental effects, so why use a secondary source when primary sources are readily available? There are a number of sites that document standards such as `printf` format strings and all of them are superior to Wikipedia.

Comment: @beroal I am not using SML/NJ at all. It's not needed to reproduce your bug. Try taking SML/NJ out of the picture and I think you'll find your code still doesn't work.

Comment: @Carey Gregory: I clearly stated that invocation from C works as expected.

Comment: @beroal Not for me it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion would be that there is no prototype in scope when you call the function, so the compiler performs default conversions on the arguments, which then confuses everything.

You should probably add to your GCC compiler options:

- `-Wmissing-prototypes`
- `-Wstrict-prototypes`
- `-Wold-style-definition`
- `-Wold-style-declaration`

Some older versions of GCC may not support the old-style arguments.  It may be a salutary lesson when you first add these options.  However, it very quickly becomes second nature to create code that conforms.  Make sure you include the correct headers; you should never declare an `extern` function in a source file (you should include the header that contains the official `extern` declaration).

Comment: I use a proper header file. Sorry, your compiler options do not help.